# How to locate a Javascript? It is there in HTML but not in any file

Tags: javascript

I am trying to cleanup unnecessary code in a wordpress site. I see, in html source code of the website, there is a javascript. it is adroll script, check below...

```
<script type="text/javascript">
adroll_adv_id = "4XJPGN2DSVEYBBDED4DKXK";
adroll_pix_id = "SEEYI5KV2BA53OK5YIG7IP";
(function () {
var oldonload = window.onload;
window.onload = function(){
__adroll_loaded=true;
var scr = document.createElement("script");
var host = (("https:" == document.location.protocol) ? "https://s.adroll.com" : "http://a.adroll.com");
scr.setAttribute('async', 'true');
scr.type = "text/javascript";
scr.src = host + "/j/roundtrip.js";
((document.getElementsByTagName('head') || [null])[0] ||
document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0].parentNode).appendChild(scr);
if(oldonload){oldonload()}};
}());
</script>
```

I tried to locate the above code in all possible ways.

> > checked all the plugins
> >
> > Deactivated Google Analytics plugin
> >
> > Checked functions.php
> >
> > Checked header.php and foother.php
> >
> > downloaded wntire wordpress from server and then used MX dreamweaver to find adroll in source code.

But location of the javascript is still not found.

Comment: index.php might also contains some script.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would download all files via FTP and search in the folder for `adroll_adv_id`. If there's no result then it's either in the database or obfuscated.

Comment: exported database in xml and found it.

Answer (score 0):

Do you use some template and is there a chance that is includes anywhere in it something that starts with `eval` or has adroll IDs fields in settings panel?
Or maybe you use a free hosting provider that is adding their ads on you site?
Can you share the link to the website?

Comment: i initially suspected code injection. and i checked for eval. but, did not find.